# (Func, Action, Predicate) VS Converter and Comparison delegate c#

Tags: c#, delegates

I understood Func, Action, Predicate with the help of some amazing posts available on this site and in short-

`Action` is a delegate (pointer) to a method, that takes zero, one or more input parameters, but does not return anything.

`Func` is a delegate (pointer) to a method, that takes zero, one or more input parameters, and returns a value (or reference).

`Predicate` is a special kind of `Func` often used for comparisons.

Now I'm confused in `Converter` and `Comparison` delegate,why .Net Framework introduced these 2 delegate flavours for just converting and comparing, when and how to use these 2  over existing 3.

Please provide simpler and shorter example for understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now I'm confused in Converter and Comparison delegate,why .Net Framework introduced these 2 delegate flavours for just converting and comparing, when and how to use these 2 over existing 3.

Historically, the delegates were introduced in the opposite order to the order your question suggests.

`Predicate<T>`, `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` and `Comparison<T>` were introduced in .NET 2.0. They were used by `List<T>` and a few other types. At this point in time C# didn't support lambda expressions but *did* support anonymous methods. Delegates were *mostly* used for event handling and starting threads... supporting them for predicates, conversion and comparison was a baby step, effectively.

Note that `Predicate<T>` isn't used for *comparisons* - it's used for *testing* a single value. For example, you could have a `Predicate<string>` for "Is the string length more than 5 characters?" `Comparison<T>`, however, *is* for comparing values - it's used for sorting.

The `Func` and `Action` delegates were (mostly - `Action<T>` was in .NET 2.0; used by `List<T>.ForEach`) introduced in .NET 3.5, with LINQ. That was the time frame in which C# 3 introduced lambda expressions and its LINQ support as well, and suddenly delegates were everywhere. I believe the level of awareness of delegates (and how they could be used) went up *massively* with C# 3.

Early pre-releases of LINQ used `Predicate<T>` instead of `Func<T, bool>`, but then additional overloads of `Where` were introduced accepting `Func<T, int, bool>` to allow the index to be part of the predicate.

I *suspect* that if the framework were redesigned from scratch, the "special purpose" delegates (`Predicate<T>`, `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` and `Comparison<T>`) might not exist. It's possible that `Predicate<T>` and `Comparison<T>` would still exist, as they provide additional semantic hints as to the purpose of the delegate which can help readability - but `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` really doesn't have any benefits over `Func<T, TResult>`.

Comment: could you please edit the answer and provide some snippet just for understanding like how to use these 2 new types.

Comment: @LogicalDesk: Which types do you believe to be "new"? (All the types described have been around for nearly 10 years...)

Comment: I was not aware of Comparison and converter that's why I said them new, sorry for that.

Comment: @LogicalDesk: Please read my answer more carefully then - the history *matters* here. You're asking why X was introduced when Y could already handle everything - which doesn't make as much sense when you know that X came first.

Comment: you are legend @Jon, I have gone through your books and they are also amazing as you are.